# Startup script sometimes fails - rc.local virtual machine

Tags: 12.04, startup, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, openstack

I've added simple line:

```
python <path-to-my-script> &
```

to /etc/rc.local, but I've noticed that after migration from one host to the other one, the script sometimes fails.

I'm using KVM, VM's are under Ubuntu 12.04 32-bits. Host's have Ubuntu 12.04 64-bits and I'm using Live Migration (private cloud built with Openstack).

I don't know it's KVM/Libvirt's fault or maybe I'm doing something wrong on Ubuntu or maybe it's cloud software's fault?

Could it be rc.local fault? Is there something what I should to know, when I'm using rc.local and it may be a cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a 10 second pause before the script command. Sometimes rc.local runs too soon....

Example:

```
...
# By default this script does nothing.
sleep 10 
python <path-to-my-script> &
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if isn't your program that is crashing. The easiest way to do that is to redirect its output to a file and inspect it later (feel free to replace /myprogram.log to something else):

```
python <path-to-my-script> &>/myprogram.log &
```

Also, check that `rc.local` has the following line at the end

```
exit 0
```

and it is executable. You can check that using `ls -la /etc/rc.local`. It should display something like this:

```
ls -la /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 629 Aug 10 19:41 /etc/rc.local
```

If that's not the case you can make it executable issuing `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Nah it's not the case. I've already checked everything you wrote :) Also I don't have errors on standard output and diagnostic output. It looks like python is just exiting and I don't know why. I created simple while-loop with threads where I'm generating 100% cpu usage and it doesn't work sometimes after migration. Only after migration and sometimes not every time. I'll check migration documentation. Maybe hypervisor is re-running services after migration and because it's only in rc.local it doesn't start properly.